# "Slow" Connection String in dbml?

Tags: asp.net, sql, dbml

i have a dbml-file which I use for my linq to SQL.
As i never learned it better, I use the server-explorer from visual studio, insert my database-information there and drag and drop the tables from the db to the dbml file.
The first time I did this i got asked if I want to save every information in the file itself and agree...

So the connection string is with "mysite.com/SQLEXPRESS".

Now I ask myself 2 things:

1) is there any known problem with the safe in file-option suggested by VS?

2) Is this slow, because when I publish my site on mysite.com, does asp.net route the database-connection outsite the LAN and then inside again, beacuse I use the domain here, instead of using localhost/SQLEPXRESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Are you experiencing issues?  If not then you're good.  If you are, then please ask a question that specifically outlines any problems you are actually facing.

2) Completely depends on how your own network is setup.  If the machine knows it is named mysite.com then it will resolve itself.  If not then it will have to ask the configured DNS server where that is.  If the site name is a proxy then it will likely go out to the proxy then redirect back in.  Typically you use the regular machine name; even more typically the database isn't on the same machine as the website in order to provide an additional layer of security by denying direct outside access to it.